# How can I make a column sortable in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Shopcart_Abandoned_Grid?

Tags: admin, collection, grid

I need to make `created_at` and `updated_at` sort-able in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Shopcart_Abandoned_Grid`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Override the block and make sortable as true.

```
$this->addColumn('updated_at', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Updated At'),
        'width'     =>'170px',
        'type'      =>'datetime',
        'index'     =>'updated_at',
        'filter_index'=>'main_table.updated_at',
        'sortable'  =>true
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in theory is correct, but in reality is not. I try this before I put this question :D - If you try you'll see that this doesn't make sortable that column.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work is because the collection is built using the function `prepareForAbandonedReport`. In this function the order by is hard-coded to `updated_dat` :(

```
public function prepareForAbandonedReport($storeIds, $filter = null)
{
    $this->addFieldToFilter('items_count', array('neq' => '0'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', '1')
        ->addSubtotal($storeIds, $filter)
        ->addCustomerData($filter)
        ->setOrder('updated_at');
    if (is_array($storeIds) && !empty($storeIds)) {
        $this->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
    }


    return $this;
}
```

So what you will have to do is either update the collection in the function `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Shopcart_Abandoned_Grid::_prepareCollection` or rewrite the function `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection::prepareForAbandonedReport` so that it does not hard code the order.

For me I would think that it would be "easier" and maybe a bit cleaner to do it inside the `_prepareCollection` function as you only have to change a single block that is only used for the purpose of abandoned carts and not the general reports collection.

Answer (score 0):

I try all but what I finally do is:

In _prepareCollection() =>

I add this:

```
$sort = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sort');
$dir = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dir');
if (isset($sort) && isset($dir)) {
    $collection
        ->getSelect()
        ->order("$sort $dir");
}
```